Set same scale in legend matplotlib
I'm working with geospacial data and I have two pandas dataframes with two different regions, both have a column geometry with the (multi)polygons and a column SCORE with a value for each of the (multi)polygons I want to plot.
For example, this is the plot for the provinces of Spain excluding Canary Islands:
shapefile_prov.plot(column="SCORE", legend=True)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])


And this is the plot of the dataframe with Canary Island:
shapefile_prov_can.plot(column="SCORE", legend=True)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])


Is there a way to colour the graph for Canary Islands with the same scale of colours of the first graph? What I mean is that yellow colour should be associated to values of SCORE roughly above 0.5 and purple for values below 0.325 approximately.

A quick/simple option would be to agg the min/max of scores and pass it to the plot :
cmap_range = shapefile_prov["SCORE"].agg({"vmin": "min", "vmax": "max"})

shapefile_prov_can.plot(column="SCORE", legend=True, **cmap_range)

NB: The plot below uses an AxesDivider to improve the appearance of the colorbar.


You may use the plt.clim(minValue, maxValue) function to set the color range min/max.
Using these on both charts will render them both with the same color scale where the same color represents the same value.
Further reading:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clim.html
Set Colorbar Range

